# Rails views helper don't seems to work with render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I try to convert rails views into pdf with the gem wicked_pdf.
But when I do a render_to_string like this

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(template: "templates/pdf_meteo.html.erb", locals: {communaute_meteo_id: id}, layout: 'pdf')
```

Methods like `user_path` don't work and return undefined method error... (note that the page work properly if I render it in html)
If someone can help me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `render_to_string` will not give you access to Rails URL helpers. One workaround is to include them directly in the `locals` that you pass into the PDF template using something like `url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`:

```rb
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
  template: "templates/pdf_meteo.html.erb",
  locals: {url: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers, communaute_meteo_id: id}
  layout: 'pdf'
)
```

And then inside of your PDF template you would call them with:

```rb
url.user_path
```

Keep in mind that by default the `_path` URL helpers will be **relative**, and not absolute paths. You can instead use the `_url` version of the helpers and set the `host` for them in a few different ways. You can configure them globally for your entire app:

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'www.mysite.com'
```

or set them individually on each helper inside of your PDF template:

```rb
url.user_url(host: 'www.mysite.com')
```

Hope that gets you what you need!

Comment: Thanks, god ! I will check with this

Answer (score 5):

You can include helpers by using the following method

```rb
ac = ActionController::Base.new
ac.view_context_class.include(ActionView::Helpers, ApplicationHelper)
ac.render_to_string(template: "templates/pdf_meteo.html.erb", locals: {communaute_meteo_id: id}, layout: 'pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use regular rails rendering flow - with view file `your_action_name.pdf.erb`, trick is in overriding `formats` for partials:

```
<%= render partial:"some_partial", formats:[:html] %>
```

Also you can run `render_to_string` in context of your controller to have helpers (because `ActionController::Base` knows nothing about your app)